# Can't get TradingView alerts to pop up with my strategy

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern, alerts, tradingview-api

I can't for the life of me get my tradingview alerts to pop up even though my strategy is indicating a buy signal correctly. I need the alert to pop up so it can be read by the trading bot.

Current code:

```
// 1. Determine Long Trade Entry

enterLong = cross(low, TRbottom2)

alertcondition(enterLong, title='Position Opened', message="Test")
```

---

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I tried setting an alert on the chart but I don't get a drop down its just an alert on the indicator and it doesn't trigger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your `TRbottom2` value never cross `low` value.

This one works:

```
//@version=4
study("Cross Alert Test", overlay = true)

float sma50 = sma(close, 50)
float sma20 = sma(close, 20)

plot(sma50, "SMA 50", color.red)
plot(sma20, "SMA 20", color.blue)

bool smaCross = cross(sma50, sma20)

bgcolor(smaCross ? color.green : na)

alertcondition(smaCross, "SMA 20 cross SMA 50", "Crossed!")
```

Comment: Thanks, well it would be the low of the candle crossing the TRBottom2 indicator. When plotting the strategy it plots the opening of the long correctly, so that should also activate the alert at the same time, I am trying the following code as an alternative

if testPeriod() and enterLong and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", long=true, alert_message = message_long_entry)

Comment: I've noticed with the script that you posted that it gives me a drop down menu to select the specific alert condition when I go to set the alert, my script isn't giving me a drop down menu. Is that because it's a Strategy and not a Study? Would making it a study fix that?